# Как спарсить цену?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Хочу вытащить цену с вот этого вот сайта:

https://winauto.ua/?match=all&subcats=y&pcode_from_q=y&pshort=y&pfull=y&pname=y&pkeywords=y&search_performed=y&q=gazer&dispatch=products.search

Как это можно было бы реализовать? Ведь они цену пишут не с помощью текста, как на большинстве сайтов, у них она выставляется jpg файлов, а то что в атрибуте  не подходит, потому что эта цена не актуальная.

То как я сейчас вытягиваю цену, но это неверная цена:
`product_price = item.select_one('.ty-price-update img[title]')`

Вот пример одного из элементов:

```html
<img src="https://winauto.ua/index.php?dispatch=products.show_price&amp;pr=YDJlODkzNDcwMDRkODY2ZWUxY2Q3YWJjM2QzYTBiOTAToyOntpOjA7ZDo5NTE5O2k6MTthOjI6e2k6MDtzOjEwOiJkaXNjb3VudGVkIjtpOjE7czo1OiJwcmljZSI7fX0%3D" alt="9999 грн." title="Цена: 9999 грн.">
```

upd.22.10.21

Немного переделал код, теперь он выглядит вот так:
https://dpaste.org/RefK

То как цена выглядит на самом сайте:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RdBF.png]

Comment: В атрибуте `alt` ведь есть цена, а хотя там старая...

Comment: В этом и проблема, достать этот атрибут не проблема, но она не подходит

Comment: то есть, задача сводится к тому, что бы декодировать картинку в текст?

Comment: Да, но как это сделать и при этом еще занести в таблицу?

Comment: придется на каждый товар делать ещё один запрос, скачивать эти картинки. Я заметил, что размеры картинок стабильны, а это значит, что можно просто проверять черный/белый пиксель в нескольких местах и определять цифру. Ну или нейронку натравить, если хочется чего то крутого и модернового.

Comment: Я думал по поводу нейронки, но здраво оценивая свои знания я получу модерновый взрыв мозга пока буду разбирать ее

Comment: При том сайт нормальный, парсится без проблем, но вот эта вот цена это единственная проблема

Comment: да просто нужно на сайт наехать, что у него плохо с accessibility (то есть, для тех, кто плохо видит или подобное).  Сами включат:)

Comment: Как вариант, но пока они включат мне этот парсер даром не сдатся :)

Comment: PyTesseract для цены в формате jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цену без скидки вы вытянуть можете, и размер скидки там есть:

data-placeholders='a:1:{s:10:"[discount]";i:8;}'

```
        <div class="ab-stickers-container ab-stickers-container__TL column-filling">
            <div class="ab-sticker-full_size" data-ab-sticker-id="26-a727-ru-862df7f640792cb6965c63c555033fd3" data-placeholders='a:1:{s:10:&quot;[discount]&quot;;i:8;}'></div>
            <div class="ab-sticker-full_size" data-ab-sticker-id="27-d811-ru"></div>
        </div>
```

Дальше, думаю, труда не составит посчитать...

Comment: А как мне вытянуть только число скидки, без слово "Акция"? Или как-то удалить это слово с помощью регулярок? Так то идея супер.

Comment: Скидка внутри <code>ab-stickers-container ab-stickers-container__TL.column-filling div:first[data-placeholders] в сериализованном виде. Десериализируйте, там в объкте discount и будет конкретно число\размер скидки.

Comment: Да, я то уже понял и сделал, все работает просто супер, вот как у меня получилось: https://dpaste.org/SDgG

Comment: @Zombotron, глаз-алмаз :)